# How to compare two folders and add/remove files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two different folders (old and new) with child-folders and .xml files. I need to know which files was added or removed (not edited!) in new folder relative to old folder. How to do this with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest one  (will be looking recursively for all XML files in folder(s)):

```
    $folder1 = ""
$folder2 = ""

$fol1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder1 -Filter *.xml| select name, directory, CreationTime
$fol2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder2 -Filter *.xml| select name, directory, CreationTime

Compare-Object $fol1 $fol2 -Property name -PassThru | select name, CreationTime, @{
    N = "Folder"; e= {
        if ($_.sideindicator -eq "=>") { "Not Found in $folder2" }
        elseif ($_.sideindicator -eq "<=") { "Not Found in $folder1" }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Name                  CreationTime            Folder
----                  ------------            ------
New Text Document.txt 7/5/2017 1:24:35 PM     Not Found in G:\xxx
1.exe                 6/14/2017 3:17:29 PM    Not Found in G:\111
1.dll                 6/14/2017 3:17:37 PM    Not Found in G:\1
```